# Assign an existing javascript array to a property in object notation

Tags: javascript, json

I'm localizing a menu and I want to assign a declared array to an object property in that way:

```
var menuListLocal=["Home","Play","Options","Exit"];

var menu_Controller={
 _menuList: menuListLocal,
 // .... //
}
```

Sorry if it is too obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear from your post what your problem is.

Comment: Uuhm this should work? Only thing, you should remove the last , Only use a , to separate properties not at the end...

Comment: I second @jeffamaphone, not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have should work, keeping in mind ropstah's comment.

```
var menuListLocal=["Home","Play","Options","Exit"];

var menu_Controller={
 _menuList: menuListLocal,
 _other: 'Something'
};
```

Usage sample:

```
var home = menuListLocal._menuList[0];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the usage sample be: `var home = menu_Controller._menuList[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it's not working.  If John's answer doesn't clear it up for you, try explicitly setting it in an init() method on your menu_Controller:

```
var menuListLocal=["Home","Play","Options","Exit"];

var menu_Controller={
   _menuList: null,

   init : function (){
       menu_Controller._menuList = menuListLocal;
   }

}
menu_Controller.init();
```